# Tabbed Content/Table Orientation

Tags: jquery, html, css

If you look at my Fiddle, I am trying to get the image table aligned to the right of the tabbed content.  I can't seem to get in the right position.  I am very new to coding so, I'm sure that coding is quite a mess but, I'm trying to learn.  If you look at this link: http://www.realtimehockey.net/education.html I want to the orientation of both the image table and the tabbed content to mirror this set up.  Any help would be appreciated as I know this is probably a fairly easy fix but, I just can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks in advance.

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7tg90tzf/

CSS

```
.tabs input[type=radio] {
display:none;
}

.tabs {
width: 800px;
height: 800px;
float: none;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
padding: 0;
margin: 5px;
}

.tabs li{
float: left;
}

.tabs label {
display: block;
padding: 10px 20px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: patua one;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
background: linear-gradient(#080808, #454545);
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
}

.tabs label:hover {
background: #ff6600;
}

.tab-content {
z-index: 2;
display: none;
left: 0;
width: 725px;
height: 773px;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 140%;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
box-sizing: border-box;
border:1px solid #454545;
border-top: 7px solid #454545;
background-color:#ffffff;
}
[id^=tab]:checked + label {
background: #ff6600;
color: white;
top: 0;
}

[id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {
display: block;
}

</style>
<style id="OrgsAtoD_19563_Styles">
<!--table
{mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
.xl1519563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:black;
font-size:11.0pt;
font-weight:400;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:General;
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
mso-background-source:auto;
mso-pattern:auto;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl6519563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:#0563C1;
font-size:11.0pt;
font-weight:400;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:underline;
text-underline-style:single;
font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:General;
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:#D8D8D8;
mso-pattern:black none;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl6619563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:black;
font-size:12.0pt;
font-weight:700;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Candara;
mso-generic-font-family:auto;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:General;
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:#D8D8D8;
mso-pattern:black none;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl6719563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:#0563C1;
font-size:12.0pt;
font-weight:700;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:underline;
text-underline-style:single;
font-family:Candara;
mso-generic-font-family:auto;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:General;
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:#D8D8D8;
mso-pattern:black none;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl6819563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:#0563C1;
font-size:11.0pt;
font-weight:400;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:underline;
text-underline-style:single;
font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:General;
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:white;
mso-pattern:black none;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl6919563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:black;
font-size:12.0pt;
font-weight:700;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Candara;
mso-generic-font-family:auto;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:General;
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:white;
mso-pattern:black none;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl7019563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:#0563C1;
font-size:11.0pt;
font-weight:700;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:General;
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:#D8D8D8;
mso-pattern:black none;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl7119563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:#0563C1;
font-size:11.0pt;
font-weight:700;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:General;
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:white;
mso-pattern:black none;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl7219563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:black;
font-size:12.0pt;
font-weight:700;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Candara, sans-serif;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:General;
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
mso-background-source:auto;
mso-pattern:auto;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl7319563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:white;
font-size:11.0pt;
font-weight:700;
font-style:italic;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:"Patua One", monospace;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:General;
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:#FF6600;
mso-pattern:black none;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl7419563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:#0563C1;
font-size:11.0pt;
font-weight:700;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:"\@";
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:#D8D8D8;
mso-pattern:black none;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl7519563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:#0563C1;
font-size:11.0pt;
font-weight:700;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:"\@";
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:white;
mso-pattern:black none;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl7619563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:#0563C1;
font-size:11.0pt;
font-weight:700;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:"\@";
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:#D9D9D9;
mso-pattern:black none;
white-space:nowrap;}
.xl7719563
{padding-top:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
mso-ignore:padding;
color:#0563C1;
font-size:11.0pt;
font-weight:700;
font-style:normal;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
mso-font-charset:0;
mso-number-format:General;
text-align:general;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:#D9D9D9;
mso-pattern:black none;
white-space:nowrap;}

#table-wrapper {
position:relative;
}
#table-scroll {
height:700px;
width: auto;
overflow:auto;  
margin-top:10px;
}
#table-wrapper table {
width:auto;

}
#table-wrapper table * {

}
#table-wrapper table thead th .text {
position:absolute;   
top:-20px;
z-index:2;
height:20px;
width:auto;
}
```

I have more characters than the allotted 30,000 so you can find the HTML code in the Fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some starting divs missing in the html - it all starts with ul but then there are 3 divs ending after the ul closes, so we can't see those divs.  Also in the `<div class="w-col w-col-4"><div class="w-embed">` - those divs are missing the closing tags after the table too.  So there's something there we can't see.  Other than that to point you to the direction, you can just float your tabs table left, and float the image table right, then clear your floats, or use display:inline-block.  So something like:

```
.tabs {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.w-col {
float:right;
width: 200px;
}
```

Then after the `.w-col` divs, add `<div style="clear:both"></div>`

As long as the div that wraps all the code has a set width you should be good.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I figured it was something simple that I probably screwed up.  Appreciate.